# Problema de classe de entidade incompleta - JPA

Tags: java, jpa, netbeans

Pessoal estou tentando fazer o relacionamento entre duas classe (CotDetatlhe e CotDetForn), mas estou enfrentando o seguinte problema:

> The @JoinColumns on the annotated element [field cotDetatlhe] from the entity class [class bean.CotDetForn] is incomplete. When the source entity class uses a composite primary key, a @JoinColumn must be specified for each join column using the @JoinColumns. Both the name and the referencedColumnName elements must be specified in each such @JoinColumn.

Logo a baixo estão os códigos:

CotDetatlhe:

```
public class CotDetatlhe implements Serializable {
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "cod_req_cab", referencedColumnName = "cod_req_cab", insertable = false, updatable = false),
        @JoinColumn(name = "cod_produto", referencedColumnName = "cod_produto", insertable = false, updatable = false)})
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private ReqDet reqDet
    ///******* Relação com a classe CotDetForn
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "cotDetatlhe")
    private Collection<CotDetForn> CotDetFornCollection;
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @EmbeddedId
    protected CotDetatlhePK cotDetatlhePK;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "cod_req_det")
    private int codReqDet;
    @JoinColumn(name = "cod_cot_cab", referencedColumnName = "cod_cot_cab", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private CotCab cotCab;
```

CotDetForn:

```
public class CotDetForn implements Serializable {
    @Transient
    private PropertyChangeSupport changeSupport = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @EmbeddedId
    protected CotDetFornPK cotDetFornPK;
    @Column(name = "desconto")
    private Integer desconto;
    // @Max(value=?)  @Min(value=?)//if you know range of your decimal fields consider using these annotations to enforce field validation
    ////**** Relação com a classe CotDetatlhe
    @JoinColumn(name = "cod_req_det", referencedColumnName = "cod_req_det", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private CotDetatlhe cotDetatlhe;
```

CotDetFornPK:

```
@Embeddable 
public class CotDetFornPK implements Serializable {
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "cod_det_forn")
    private int codDetForn;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "cod_cot_forn")
    private int codCotForn;
    @Column(name = "cod_req_det")
    private int codReqDet;
```

CotDetatlhePK:

```
@Embeddable
public class CotDetatlhePK implements Serializable {
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "cod_cot_cab")
    private int codCotCab;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "cod_req_cab")
    private int codReqCab;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "cod_produto")
    private String codProduto;
```

Comment: Qual o código da classe CotDetatlhePK? Para deixar a pergunta mais enxuta, seria interessante também limpar das classes campos que não fazem parte do problema (como os atributos Double, por exemplo)

Comment: Vlw pela dica @Dherik, ja enxuguei o código, somente com o necessário e postei o código da Tabela CotDetatlhePK

Answer (score 1):

Você está tentando referenciar uma entidade CotDetatlhe que tem chave provavelmente composta (CotDetatlhePK).

Se você quer relacionar CotDetatlhe a partir de CotDetForn, você precisa especificar cada coluna de CotDetatlhePK como JoinColumn dentro de um JoinColumns em CotDetForn.

Da forma como fez o relacionamento de cotDetatlhe em CotDetForn, você não estava tentando referenciar a PK composta de CotDetatlhe.

Comment: então no caso dentro da @JoinColumns na CotDetForn eu coloco os campos das CotDetatlhePK é isto?

Answer (score 1):

Pessoal resolvi meu problema da seguinte forma:

```
public class CotDetForn implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @EmbeddedId
    protected CotDetFornPK cotDetFornPK;

    //// troquei o @JoinColumn pelo @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "cod_req_det", referencedColumnName = "cod_req_det")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private CotDetatlhe codReqDet;
```

pesquisei nos fóruns e encontrei esta solução que até agora resolveu meu problema.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B32110_01/web.1013/b28221/cmp30cfg001.htm